# Need help passing dynamic list of files to partial. Can't get list to pass successfully in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu, partials, local-variables

In my application/index, the user selects a location and directory path from a drop down list. onchange event makes a call to the controller called file_dir where it takes the path, executes a command line call passing back a list of files in that directory to a parameter @files.  I then render a partial passing this @files to a local variable. Then in the partial the select tag will display with the list of file passed to it.

I am new to ROR and have not been able to successfully pass a readable local variable. to the partial. Everything works fine with a hardcoded line but not with the local variable.

Can someone please help advise me on the correct way to set this up?

Here is the method called from the first onchange dropdown pass that receives the directory:

```
 def file_dir
    unless params[:dir_list].nil?
      @dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list]
    else  
      @dir_path_choice = '/watchfolder/indemandvod'
    end  
#   @files = "#{@dir}"    
    @files = Dir.glob("#{@dir_path_choice}/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map
    if @files.nil?
      @files = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/hbovod/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map
    end
    render :partial => 'list_files', :locals => { @list => @files }
  end
```

In irb I tested the @files = Dir.glob("#{@dir_path_choice}/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map line to make sure this was processing correctly. Here is what @files looks like:

```
1.9.3-p547 :008 > @files
 => #<Enumerator: ["/watchfolder/indemandvod/MJR-TEST.mov", "/watchfolder/indemandvod/MJR-TEST-AWS1.mov", "/watchfolder/indemandvod/MJR-TEST-AWS.mov", "/watchfolder/indemandvod/MJR-TEST2.mov", "/watchfolder/indemandvod/PIX_Gor_SVO40185/PIX_Gor_SVO40185_mezz.mov"]:map>
```

This data breaks out in the select list, separated by the commas.

NOTE: I did try to pass the @list without the @ symbol but I got unidentified local variable or method and couldn't get the code to run with out adding the @.  This is like a collection of data so I expect it is interpreting it as an array.  Not sure though.

Here is the partial file code:

```
  <p>          
        <label>Select Partial Test File List:</label><%= @list %><br />
        <% unless @list.nil? %>
            <%= @list %>
        <% else %>
          <label> list is empty. </label>
          <% @list = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/showtimevod/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map %>
        <% end %>
        <%= select_tag 'filepath', options_for_select(@list, @selected_filepath) %> 
  </p>
```

It does display back on the page and my 'list is empty' always shows and the dropdown box populates with my default 'hardcoded' command line for '/watchfolder/showtimevod/' files list.

The @selected_filepath maintains the selected line in the list.

I don't know what I am doing wrong in passing values to partials.

Comment: When you took away the `@` from the `@list` in the controller, did you also take it away from all of the `@list` references in the partial? You only gave us _part_ of an error message, so it is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> In my application/index,

What is an "application/index"?

> Can someone please help advise me on the correct way to set this up?

The correct way is to get something simple to work first:

app/controllers/some_controller.rb

```
  def file_dir
    puts "****#{params[:dir_list]}"
    @files = %w[ a b c]

    render :partial => 'list_files', :locals => { file_names => @files }
  end
```

views/some_controller/_list_files.htm.erb:

```
<div>

<%= file_names.each do |fname| %>
<div><%= fname %></div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

And as with all your posts, in this line:

```
<%= select_tag(
       'filepath', 
       options_for_select(@list, @selected_filepath) %>
```

@selected_filepath is undefined.

> This is like a collection of data so I expect it is interpreting it as
>   an array. Not sure though.

You should probably strive to create data that you understand.  What are you trying to accomplish with this line:

```
@files = Dir.glob("#{@dir_path_choice}/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map
```

that the following line doesn't do:

```
@files = Dir.glob("#{@dir_path_choice}/**/*.{mpg,mov}")
```

This:

> I did try to pass the @list without the @ symbol but I got
>   unidentified local variable or method and couldn't get the code to run
>   with out adding the @.

is not sufficient.  No one cares what your interpretation of the error message is--what people care about is the EXACT error message, with file names and line numbers, copy and pasted into your post, along with the exact code the error refers to.

If you just want to get your code to work, you can do this:

app/some_controller.rb:

```
  def file_dir
    if params[:dir_list].nil?
      @dir_path_choice = '/watchfolder/indemandvod'
    else  
      @dir_path_choice = params[:dir_list]
    end 

    @files = Dir.glob("#{@dir_path_choice}/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map

    if @files.nil?
      @files = Dir.glob("/watchfolder/hbovod/**/*.{mpg,mov}").map
    end

    render :partial => 'list_files', :locals => {file_names => @files }
  end
```

However, adding map() to the end of your Dir.glob() does nothing useful.

app/views/some_controller/_list_files.html.erb:

```
<p>          
  <label>Select Partial Test File List:</label>
  <%= select_tag 'filepath', options_for_select(file_names) %> 
</p>
```